# Using Chebyshev's inequality to solve a problem

Tags: probability

> We toss an unbiased coin until obtain heads. We denote the amount of throws needed to get heads by $Y$. Find an upper bound $Z$ for $Y$ such that the statement "the first heads will be obtained at throw $Z$ at the latest" has a probability of at least 95%.

So I recognised the distribution of the random variable $Y$ as a geometric distribution, so the mean $\mu = \dfrac{1}{p} = 2$ and the variance $V(Y) = \dfrac{1-p}{p^2} = 2$, and hence $\sigma = \sqrt{2}$.

Then I decided to use Chebyshev for this problem, i.e. a fraction of at least $1-\dfrac{1}{k^2}$ of our observations is between $\mu - ks$ and $\mu + ks$. If we use $1-\dfrac{1}{k^2} = 0.95$, we get that $k=\sqrt{20}$ and thus $\mu + ks = 2 + \sqrt{40}$, and thus we find that we need 9 throws to satisfy the statement.

Is this correct? The main part I'm worried about is setting $1-\dfrac{1}{k^2} = 0.95$. I'm not sure if that is correct.

Comment: Overall, it looks like you are using, for real numbers $k \geq 0$,  $$P[|Y-E[Y]|\geq k\sigma] = P[(Y-E[Y])^2 \geq k^2\sigma^2] \leq \frac{E[(Y-E[Y])^2]}{k^2\sigma^2} = \frac{1}{k^2}$$

Comment: So, in other words, looks good, provided you define $s=\sigma$.